# How Can I Update the ListView using "onProgressChanged" method of the SeekBar?

Tags: android, listview, android-seekbar

I have a simple layout have only

1 SeekBar "seekBar"

and

1 ListView "listView"

How Can I Update the ListView using "onProgressChanged" method of the SeekBar ?

What code should be used ?

```
package ahmed_smae.timestables;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Member Variables...

```
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Integer> numbersArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

onCreate method

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Build List

```
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
            numbersArrayList.add(i);
        }
```

Activate SeekBar and ListView

```
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.numbersListView);
```

link Adapter

```
        final ArrayAdapter<Integer> numberListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbersArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(numberListAdapter);


        seekBar.setMin(numberListAdapter.getItem(0));
        seekBar.setMax(numberListAdapter.getCount() + 1);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                Log.i("TimesTable", "" + i);
```

set code to update the ListView "listView" items with the SeekBar Progress Change

What Code Goes Here?

```
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy you can Refresh Adapter by using.

```
numberListAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: I tried it. it resets the progress of the SeekBar to 0 only when i select the ListView

Answer (score 0):

Just put the numberArraysList inside onProgressChanged method of OnSeekBarChangeListener. Like this...

```
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            ArrayList<Integer> numbersArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Log.i("TimesTable", "" + i);
```